# How to get only 1 parameter without repeating from array

Tags: php

How to get only 1 parameter without repeating from array?

`$a = array("5WG", "5WG", "6WG", "6WG", "3WG", "2WG");`

I want to return a result:

`5WG
6WG
3WG
2WG`

(if there is a recurring one, it will only show 1 at a time)

Comment: Have you tried to solve this yourself yet?

Comment: `array_unique()` is what you are looking for https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: Yes, i tried with `if()` but it doesn't

Comment: @catcon , it doesn't work

Comment: It should: https://3v4l.org/KVIr9

Comment: @catcon, don't go with that, i want to import them afterwards in mysql

Comment: Then you should add that and explain what you are trying to do in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

also u can do with this code

```
$new_arr = array();
$a = array("5WG", "5WG", "6WG", "6WG", "3WG", "2WG");

foreach( $a as $k => $v ) {
  if( ! in_array( $v, $new_arr ) ) {
       $new_arr[] = $v;
  }
}

var_dump( $new_arr );
```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

```
<?php

$a = array("5WG", "5WG", "6WG", "6WG", "3WG", "2WG");
$a = array_unique($a);

print_r($a);
```

Comment: don't go with that, i want to import them afterwards in mysql

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to do. `echo implode(PHP_EOL, array_unique($a));`

Answer (score 1):

You should php buitin funciton to remove duplicate values.

```
$unique_value_array = array_unique($your_array);
```

read more : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php